# Traducción de "ripped the pish[piss] out of"

Tags: traducción, diferencias-regionales, significado-en-contexto

> He had **ripped the pish out of** her in that pub, and now he was going to f****** well get it.

Lo que hizo él es que no la tomó mucho en cuenta en el pub y después de salir del pub la embarazó y con los días tampoco la tomó en cuenta y se desentendió de su embarazo, es decir, no la acompañó y le dijo que esa guagua no era de él.

Pish es piss. Vacilar es to joke, fool around. Take the piss (out). Piss about es agarrar para el chuleteo, tomar el pelo, messing with her. Entonces en este contexto la traducción sería: que él **no la estaba tomando en serio** en el pub, **se hizo el loco**, **la ignoró**, **no la pescó**, que no se había comportado bien con ella y queda confirmado con lo que hizo después y por eso quieren golpearlo los parientes de ella.

Comment: For me _rip the piss_ is quite a strong form of mockery so I suspect _no tomar en serio_ is not quite strong enough.

Comment: *Le estaba chingue y chingue*... *Le echaba harta carrilla*... *No paraba de burlarse de ella*...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Literalmente podríamos decir que "To have the piss ripped out of you" (ridiculizar completamente), significaría que se echa o se lleva el pis en gran cantidad, una especie de (meada o ridiculización) "para ti".

De forma figurada se refiere a "hacer pis" o "una meada" a una persona con el propósito de lograr un efecto de burla cómica o tomadura de pelo a expensas del otro.

La intención figurada es la de derramar o llevar "ese líquido" (hasta ti), para que la gente al ver esa (meada) encima tuyo y verte ridiculizado, se ría por ello.

En español de España y dentro de una expresión coloquial, podríamos decir que es la forma inversa del sentido de "meada", cuando alguien nos dice, "¡Que meada tío!", como haber hecho un ridículo espantoso frente a algo o alguien. En este caso se llevaría ese "ridículo espantoso", esa "meada", sobre otra persona. Igual que en español tenemos la expresión "cagarse en alguien", en inglés tienen "mearse en alguien", como sinónimo de ridiculizar.

La expresión en sí sería una mezcla entre "se burlaron mucho de mí" y "me ridiculizó a sus anchas". Algo así como "Mearse de la risa encima de alguien de forma sarcástica y cruel con el fin de ridiculizarla".

- "El la había ridiculizado espantosamente en el pub".
- "El la había avergonzado por los cuatro costados en el pub"
- "El se había jactado de ella en el pub".

Comment: Lamentablemente no hay ningún diálogo que indique una burla descarada aparte de la narración "He had ripped the pish out of her in that pub" e incluso aunque el personaje es machista y misógeno no se burlaría de una mujer en una forma tan obvia como lo haría con un hombre(en otros libros sí se ha jactado con sus amigos de haber abusado sexualmente de otras mujeres, pero con ella fue más bien frio en el pub) No hay nada que indiqué eso, todo lo contrario, que fue indiferente a su presencia. La verdadera burla sería lo que pasó afuera y después del pub, que no asumiera su responsabilidad.

Comment: Otra explicación es que tal vez los parientes no supieron donde ocurrió el hecho y hayan asumido que el contacto entre ellos, es decir, la concepción fue en el baño del pub o algo así, pero el narrador no es uno de sus parientes y eso ocurrió afuera en su casa. Y, por otro lado, el personaje no se burla de las mujeres excepto de a sus espaldas.

Comment: También pudiera ser que él la había desgarrado, con su actitud, fingiendo indiferencia, que es al fin y al cabo, una forma de burla o de entender que se esta riendo de la persona con tal comportamiento de desdén e insensibilidad. Gracias por tus comentarios.

Comment: Sí, lo leí de nuevo, el narrador no es el pariente, pero habla por él(y probablemente desconoce los hechos en detalle pero de igual forma quiere limpiar su honra) diciendo que su trato había sido insultante y que "le había vacilado a tope" que en este caso tiene el sentido de "no tener buenas intenciones porque en el fondo la desprecia" o "tener hacia otra persona una actitud engañosa porque no la respeta", es decir pasa del estado de querer denigrarla a serle indiferente, sería como tontear, no tomarla en serio, pero por el contrario en España tontear es "flirtear."

Comment: Sobre "tontear", a parte de flirtear, también depende del contexto, así puede ser "hacer, decir tonterías" o también, "jugar con". Ejem. "Estuvo tonteando con el fuego y salió ardiendo". Entiendo que posiblemente estaba "jugando con" esa persona.

Comment: Sí, sólo para que quede consignado: pasar el rato, jugar con, no llegar a ninguna parte con, vacilar, tomar el pelo, hacerle perder el tiempo, liarla, cachondear, huevear, tonteando contigo, utilizar.